# Secure way to sanitize an object (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, delete-operator

In order to avoid the JavaScript `delete` operator (ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) I am currently using object destructuring to get rid of private properties:

```
//sample helper-function in ts

const sanitizeUser = (user: User): UserSanitized => {
                const { googleData, ...rest } = user
                return rest
            }
```

My question is, if the return value `sanitizeUser` can be securely used, without the possibility to recover the `googleData` property.

Comment: Yes, this function will strip the `googleData` property an return an object where the `googleData` property does not exist, barring any sort of vulnerability in the TypeScript transpiler.

Comment: Why can the user do arbitrary operations on said object? Do you pass it to some sandboxed context, where you allow user submitted code to operate, or what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be sure that the object returned by `sanitizeUser` will not have the `googleData` property. That *probably* means there's no way to get to that property's value from that "sanitized" object, but that depends entirely on the `User` object. If the `User` object has any properties that refer back to it (as is sometimes the case with parent/child relationships), then the sanitized object returned by `sanitizeUser` will have that property too — and it will still refer to the original `User` object, so it would be possible to get to `googleData` via that property.

Here's an example of that using equivalent JavaScript code:

```js
const sanitizeUser = (user/*: User*/)/*: UserSanitized*/ => {
    const { googleData, ...rest } = user;
    return rest;
};

const user = {
    googleData: "secret data!",
};
user.self = user;

const sanitized = sanitizeUser(user);
console.log(sanitized.self.googleData); // "secret data!"
```

But if the `User` object doesn't have anything referring back to itself (directly or indirectly), then no, the sanitized object is fine and there's no way to get back to the `googleData` property from it.